# mssql for xml по 10000 записей в несколько файлов

Tags: sql, sql-server

Всем привет.
Подскажите, как мне сделать так, чтобы при формировании FOR XML, в SSMS MSSQL, разбить большой результат запроса в 1000000 записей на 10000 записей и записать в несколько файлов file1.xml, file2.xml и тд. ("разрезать" большой результат на несколько файлов по 10000 записей)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот как это сделать в SQL Server 2012 и более поздних версиях.

Это концептуальный пример.

В конце концов, вам нужно будет вызвать bcp.exe, передав выражение SQL в качестве параметра в цикле.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT PRIMARY KEY, [Description] VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO @tbl
VALUES (1, 'One')
   , (2, 'Two')
   , (3, 'Three')
   , (4, 'Four')
   , (5, 'Five')
   , (6, 'Six')
   , (7, 'Seven')
   , (8, 'Eight')
   , (9, 'Nine')
   , (10, 'Ten')
   , (11, 'Elleven')
   , (12, 'Twelve')
   , (13, 'Thirteen');
-- DDL and data population, end

DECLARE @BatchNo INT = 1
   , @NumberOfBatchesTotal DECIMAL = 3
   , @RowsPerBatch INT
   , @RowTotal INT;

-- Для расчета количества записей на каждую партию (Batch)
SET @RowTotal = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @tbl);
SET @RowsPerBatch = CEILING(@RowTotal/@NumberOfBatchesTotal);

WHILE @BatchNo <= @NumberOfBatchesTotal
BEGIN
    -- выполнить bcp.exe, передав SQL выражение ниже в качестве параметра 
    SELECT * FROM @tbl
    ORDER BY ID
        OFFSET (@BatchNo - 1) * @RowsPerBatch ROWS
        FETCH NEXT @RowsPerBatch ROWS ONLY
    FOR XML PATH('r'), TYPE, ROOT('root');

   SET @BatchNo += 1;
END;
```